# React MUI DataGrid Server Side Pagination is not working Methods are not getting called

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, pagination, datagrid

I have the following component

```
export const Setting = ({ id }) => {
const [pageState, setPageState] = useState({
    page: 0,
    pageSize: 5,
  });

  const { data: usersList, isLoading, isError } = useUsers({ id });
   
   return (
    <TableGrid
      rows={usersList?.users}
      rowCount={usersList?.totalRows ? usersList.totalRows : 0}
      isLoading={isLoading}
      pagination
      page={pageState?.page}
      pageSize={pageState?.pageSize}
      paginationMode="server"
      columns={usersColumn}
      initialState={pageState}
      getRowId={(row) => row.userId}
      onPageChange={(newPage) =>
        setPageState((old) => ({
          ...old,
          page: newPage,
        }))
      }
      onPageSizeChange={(newPageSize) =>
        setPageState((old) => ({
          ...old,
          pageSize: newPageSize,
        }))
      }
    />
  );
}
```

Here is the Common component

```
** TableGrid.jsx

const TableGrid = ({
  rows = [],
  columns = [],
  height = "100%",
  width = "100%",
  toolbar,
  isLoading,
  ...rest
}) => {
  return (
    <Stack
      sx={{
        height,
        width,
      }}
    >
      <DataGrid
        rows={rows}
        className="grid-container"
        columns={columns}
        initialState={{
          pagination: {
            paginationModel: { pageSize: 4, page: 0 },
          },
        }}
        pageSizeOptions={[5, 10, 25]}
        autoHeight={false}
        autoWidth={false}
        {...rest}
        localeText={{
          noRowsLabel: (
            <Typography variant="h5" component={"h2"} fontWeight={"normal"}>
              No Data
            </Typography>
          ),
        }}
        slots={{
          toolbar: toolbar,
        }}
        loading={isLoading}
      />
    </Stack>
  );
};
```

Now I am trying to do the server side pagination here.  But `onPageChange` and  `onPageSizeChange` these methods are not getting called even if I click on the next arrow or previous arrow.  Here, I need to pass server the limit ( number of rows to be returned ) .

Why is this pagination not working?